# Github Forked Repo Configuration

Tags: git, github

I have a fork of a corporate Github repo with a web application that I am working on.  Creating the fork and cloning it are not the problem.

I have to make initial changes to the master branch in order for the website to run locally on my machine... the `web.config` file and the publish profile.  All other work and changes will be done with branches that I will submit pull requests for.

The question that I have is how do I prevent the changes to the new `web.config` file and creation of the local publish profile from being included in any commit?
I tried ignoring the files, but now git wants to include the change to the gitignore file which I do not want either and even after ignoring the `web.config` file, git is still tracking changes.

Everytime I submit a pull request, it contains these commits that I do not want included in the pull request.

Please keep in mind that **I am not a "command-line" person** and I am a novice at best with github and gitbash.  I have been using SourceTree and GitKraken, but I am still having a difficult time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't forget to make your changes in a branch (not on master directly), in order to push that branch and make your pull request from there.

But for files you don't want to see considered for index and commit, you would need (in command line, but it is easy) to type:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged --  web.config
```

Then any modification to that file would be ignored by Git.

For files *generated* (which should not tracked at all), you can add them in your `.gitignore`, and it is not a bad idea to include said `.gitignore` in your PR.

Comment: Thanks, this helped out a lot.